# How to correctly add Sublime Text in windows context menu?

Tags: windows, batch-file, sublimetext3

I want to add the ability to open a folder with Sublime Text to the context menu, as it is by default in VS Code, I tried the following script:

```
@echo off
SET st3Path=C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe

rem add it for folders
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f
pause
```

This works, but every time I open a folder, all previous folders open in separate windows too. Can I fix it somehow?

Comment: Use quotes around the path to the exe.

Comment: ...and escape them properly for the `reg` command using `\"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `subl.exe` and not `sublime_text.exe` for carrying out this action; `subl` is meant for interacting with the running instance of Sublime (and will start it if it's not already running), while `sublime_text` is the application itself.

Regardless of that however, your issue is also (somewhat) related to this setting, which as seen here defaults to being turned on:

```
    // Exiting the application with hot_exit enabled will cause it to close
    // immediately without prompting. Unsaved modifications and open files will
    // be preserved and restored when next starting.
    //
    // Closing a window with an associated project will also close the window
    // without prompting, preserving unsaved changes in the workspace file
    // alongside the project.
    "hot_exit": true,
```

When this is enabled you can quit Sublime at any point and have it save it's session (including unsaved file changes, selection states, etc) and then restore that to put you back to where you were.

So, if you previously quit Sublime while you had windows open, then when you carry out your action above Sublime will restore it's session (and all other windows) and then create the new one.

Turning the setting off stops that from happening so that every startup of Sublime is a "clean" state with no restored windows or state. However this also implies that when you quit Sublime you need to ensure that you save changes or your work will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Given your provided information and based upon the information provided in the command help, `reg add /?`, I'd assume that your batch file should look something like this:

```bat
@Set "st3Path=%%Program Files%%\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
@Set "regPath=HKCU\Software\Classes\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"
@%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "%regPath%" /VE /D "Open with Sublime Text 3" /F >NUL
@%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "%regPath%" /V Icon /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D "\"%st3Path%\",0" /F >NUL
@%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "%regPath%\command" /VE /D "\"%st3Path%\" \"%%~1\"" /F >NUL
```

As for your Software opening previously opened 'folders', I'm sure that, you can configure the software not to reopen previous files on startup, directly in the Software or by editing its config files. That is therefore outside of the scope of your code issue, and to be dealt with separately.

You'll notice that I've used the 'Current User' registry, not the 'Local Machine', as it doesn't require to be 'Run as administrator' and you shouldn't be globally making personalization changes; not everyone wants them.
If you wish to do it for all users, however, just replace `HKCU` on line `2` with `HKLM`.

Please also note, that I have no knowledge of your software itself, so taking account of the information provided in the OdatNurd's answer, please consider whether to replace `sublime_text.exe` on line `1` with `subl.exe`

Answer (score 0):

For sublime 4 (not sure about sublime 3) on windows, you just need to **run the setup file again**.

It will ask you if you want to add it to context menu.